# how can I filter output from running program?

Tags: bash, pipe

I have this bash command:

```
find $DIR -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '*.mkv' | { 
    while read filename ; do 
        mkvmerge -o "${OUTDIR}/${filename}" "${filename}" "${filename%.mkv}.mka" "${filename%.mkv}.ass"  
    done 
}
```

this gives me following output:

```
mkvmerge v5.8.0 ('No Sleep / Pillow') built on Mar  3 2013 21:06:19
'./file.mkv': Using the demultiplexer for the format 'Matroska'.
'./file.mka': Using the demultiplexer for the format 'Matroska'.
'./file.ass': Using the demultiplexer for the format 'SSA/ASS subtitles'.
'./file.mkv' track 0: Using the output module for the format 'AVC/h.264'.
'./file.mkv' track 1: Using the output module for the format 'FLAC'.
'./file.mka' track 0: Using the output module for the format 'AC3'.
'./file.ass' track 0: Using the output module for the format 'text subtitles'.
The file './out//./file.mkv' has been opened for writing.
Progress: 9%
```

Only progress line refreshes. I want to get rid of those lines before "progress" line. First I thought I can add this in the end: `| grep "Progress"` but it's doesn't work. Is there's any solution to format the output of a running program? I know that `bar` utility can produce nice progress bar almost the same way:

[image: bar example]

I tried `2> log` and `1> log` - nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mkvmerge -o "$OUTDIR/$filename" "$filename" "${filename%.mkv}.mka" "${filename%.mkv}.ass"|(sed -n /^The/q;cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

mkvmerge has a quiet mode, try it:

> $ mkvmerge -q

Comment: with quite mode no progress bar is displayed.